# How can I reduce the height of tab handles in VS Code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

With the help of [this](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css) extension, you can change the styling of VS Code.

I want to reduce the height of filetabs to 20px. I'm using something like this:

```
.editor-group-container{
    background-color: purple;
    max-height: 0px;
}

.editor-group-container-toolbar{
    background-color: lightblue;
    max-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding:0px;margin:0px;
}
.editor-container{
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.title{
    background-color: lightblue;
    max-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}    

.primary-action-bar{
    background-color: orangered;
    max-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.monaco-action-bar .action-label{
    background-color: rgb(154, 165, 7);
    max-height: 20px;
    padding:0px;margin:0px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}  

.title-label{
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.tabs-and-actions-container{
    background-color: rgb(167, 108, 0);
    max-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.tab{
    background-color: rgb(166, 94, 168);
    max-height: 20px;
}
```

It works fine for reducing the height of tabs. However, I now have a bar in the bottom, that I cannot remove:
[image: Illustration of new bar in the bottom of the editor]

edit: The Arrow is pointing at the white area. Not at the statusbar.

So I'd like to know either:

- How do I remove the white bar?
- OR
- How do I set the tab-height properly?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77085803/836330 for reducing `tab height`.

Answer (score 3):

VS Code 1.83 offers a new setting called `window.density.editorTabHeight`. Is description:

> Controls the height of editor tabs. Also applies to the title control bar when `workbench.editor.showTabs` is disabled.

At the time of this writing, it currently only has two possible values: `"default"` and `"compact"`. I.e. it doesn't allow you to choose arbitrary values of height. But at least it's probably closer to what you want.

Comment: finally this option arrived, it's not perfect because you can't customize but it's much better than the huge tabbar we had before

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can remove below status bar.

**Steps**

1 - click setting icon of left bottom.

2 - select settings

3 - search status in search bar

4 - then uncheck first one and check.

[image: demo]

Comment: The arrow in the question was misleading. I added a note after the image. I'm not talking about the statusbar, but about the white "bar", that's above it.