# How to make editor tabs smaller in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

I'd like to shrink the size of these tabs at the top of the VSCode editor somehow.

[image: Here are the tabs I am referring to]

Comment: for a question specifically about reducing height, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59463650/11107541

Answer (score 0):

You don't sat whether you want to reduce the tab's height or width or both.  There has previously been no way to reduce a tab's height, but available in the Insiders Build v1.83 now is anew setting to do that:

```
Window > Density > Editor Tab Height

> Controls the height of editor tabs. Also applies to the title control
> bar when "Workbench > Editor: Show Tabs is disabled.

Options are "compact" and "normal"
```

The effect is not huge, but the tab height will be nearly half the height as before with the `compact` setting.