# How can I change (reduce) padding of editor tabs in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, editor, padding

The editor tabs take a lot of space in VS Code, since their padding is relatively high, I d like to reduce it to 1-2px max.

I already tried

`"workbench.editor.tabPadding": 2,`

in settings.json on user level

but it doesn't have an effect

while other changes I made (such as font-color for example) work perfectly.

Also tried to disable theme/s, etc.

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP7F1.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this for horizontal padding, and the setting name you mentioned ("workbench.editor.tabPadding") is not (as far as I know) the name of any existing VS Code setting.

If you just want to change vertical padding, VS Code 1.83 added the `window.density.editorTabHeight` setting, which you can set to `"compact"` (see also [How can I reduce the height of tab handles in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59463650/11107541)).

For workarounds for tabs taking up lots of space, take a look at the following settings:

```json
"workbench.editor.pinnedTabSizing": "shrink",
"workbench.editor.tabSizing": "shrink",
"workbench.editor.wrapTabs": true,

// for VS Code pre-1.85
"workbench.editor.tabCloseButton": "off",

// for VS Code 1.85+
"workbench.editor.tabActionCloseVisibility": false,
"workbench.editor.tabActionUnpinVisibility": false,
```

Comment: thx for commenting, i already use or played with these, they're great to know. yet i want to see the entire script name in the tab, just less padding around it. Thanx though. :)